# Suspend not working properly on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

After I  suspend my computer and then press a key or click the mouse to resume , it just do not do anything (screen remain turned off) and after trying a lot also it doesn't resume,then at last i am left with no option but to power off my laptop directly and all my data get lost.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Kubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Latitude D520; on that machine, I find that I have to *briefly* press the power button to recover from suspend, but it works correctly when I do so.  That matches my experience with my older Gateway Solo 2500; as well.  Try just a short "tap" on the power button after a test suspend; it should return to a login screen or desktop (depending on your settings) in a matter of a few seconds.